# Encountering Bus Error When Passing Struct to Thread

Tags: c

I am running into the error above trying to pass a file pointer in a struct to a thread. It is an assignment requirement to have the thread be passed this output file to write to.

```
//struct to pass file to thread 2
struct THEAD_TWO_DATA{
    FILE *outputFile;
}; 

void* ThreadTwo(void *received_struct){ 
    struct THEAD_TWO_DATA *struct_ptr = (struct THEAD_TWO_DATA*) received_struct;
    fprintf(struct_ptr->outputFile, "%d\n", globalValue);
}

int main(){
    struct THEAD_TWO_DATA *my_Struct;
    my_Struct->outputFile = fopen("hw3.out", "w");
    pthread_create(&th[1], NULL, ThreadTwo, &my_Struct);

}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "zsh: " from your title?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: “zsh: bus error” is the text of the error message; it is Z shell reporting the process crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line: `struct THEAD_TWO_DATA *my_Struct;` you declare a pointer to a structure.
But that pointer is not yet referencing anything valid!
Treat the pointer as a NULL pointer (although it might well be an invalid reference to some unknown part of memory), until you are SURE it is actually referencing valid memory.

On the next line: `my_Struct->outputFile = fopen("hw3.out", "w");`, you try to assign a value in this un-initialized, invalid structure.

You need to be sure the pointer is referencing a valid object before trying to use it.

I recommend something like:

```
int main(){
    struct THEAD_TWO_DATA my_Struct;  // Not a reference, an actual structure
    my_Struct.outputFile = fopen("hw3.out", "w");
    pthread_create(&th[1], NULL, ThreadTwo, &my_Struct); // Pass a pointer to a structure.
}
```

Note that object `my_Struct` is a temporary, local variable, and may not have a long enough duration for your use.

## *But its a start....*

Comment: Re “Treat the pointer as a NULL pointer”: No, do not do that.

Comment: Works for me with minor fixup:  https://ideone.com/NP7REK

Comment: Like I said.... you did not post enough of a complete program to solve everything.  But I answered the problem you presented.

Comment: @abelenky Thank you! Using your fix in the link the issue is now resolved!! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!